# build static website on amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i got and static website and i try use amazon s3 storage to put it on..
i create an buket in the name WEB-SITE, upload all the file in to the buket
and the click on the buket propertys and change it to static website hosting
after it i click on the url of the website but it write and got this Error:

"403 Forbidden - AccessDenied"

i read that it need to add Permissions Required to the buket..
i try to add this:

```
{
  "Version":"2015-02-01",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::WEB-SITE/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but i can not save it i got this Error:

"The XML for Routing Rules is invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this, though I get a slightly different error: "Document is invalid: Invalid Version 2015-02-01 - undefined". The problem is the `Version`. That field indicates the API version, not your own revision ID. Therefore, it shouldn't be today's date, but should be a valid S3 API version. [You *must* use this date](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Version):*

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
```

* Okay, technically, you can use 2008-10-17, AWS just suggests against it.